# Android application installation failed

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I planed and made a change in package name of an existing android application successfully and just run the project and here the application gets failed to install by giving the errors in run tab at android studio

**run tab**

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: genymotion-preview___google_nexus_5x___6_0_0___api_23___1080x1920-192.168.56.101:5555
Uploading file
    local path: G:\Project\FinalProject\build\outputs\apk\FinalProject-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/app.finalproject
Installing app.finalproject
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/app.finalproject"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/app.finalproject
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]
```

Using Genymotion or physical device as testing device.

Now the Question is **why this happened?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the authority in your application Manifest.

```
android:authorities
```

In the official [android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#auth) it says:

> To avoid conflicts, authority names should use a Java-style naming convention (such as com.example.provider.cartoonprovider).